# Calling an Array from a ForLoop

Tags: java, arrays

I'm learning java a bit and I need help calling an array while its in a For Loop, Here's my array code.
**Entire Code was Requested, Sorry If its sloppy or bad coding**

```
    import java.util.Scanner ;
       public class jakeGrim {

        public static void  main(String[] args) {
                // Local variable

                int option;
                String squareFootage="";
                int noBed = 0;
                double totalSum =0;
                String propertyCode="";
                String propertyType="";

                Scanner input = new Scanner( System.in );
                Scanner user_input = new Scanner( System.in );

  do{
                  // Display menu graphics
                System.out.println(" ");
            System.out.println("|  *****Rental Menu*******   |");
            System.out.println("|        1. Enter rental property Details     ");
            System.out.println("|        2. Enter monthly rent ( 12 Months )       ");
            System.out.println("|        3. Display Annual Rent");
            System.out.println("|        4. Display rental report       ");
            System.out.println("|        5. Display Monthly rents falling below a certain threshold       ");
            System.out.println(" ");
            System.out.println(" Please Select an option: ");
            option = input.nextInt();


  {

    switch (option) {


   case 1:


            System.out.println("Enter Rental Details: ");
            System.out.println("Property Code:            ");
            propertyCode = user_input.next();
            System.out.println("Property Type:            ");
            propertyType = user_input.next();
            System.out.println("Square Footage:           ");
            squareFootage = user_input.next();
            System.out.println("Number Of bedrooms        ");
            noBed = input.nextInt();
            break;


      case 2:

     {
                Scanner keyboardScanner = new Scanner(System.in); 
         double[] array = new double[12]; 
         for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
         System.out.println("Enter Rental for month[" +( i +1)+ "]");
         array[i] = keyboardScanner.nextDouble();
       }




       //So now, we need to do something with that array and sum up all the values in that array. 
       for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
         System.out.println(array[i]);

        totalSum += array[i];
      }
       }




        break;


            case 3:
            System.out.println("The annual rent for propery code "+propertyCode+" is:  " +    (totalSum));


       break;

    case 4:
           System.out.println(" Property Code:      "+propertyCode);
           System.out.println(" Property Type:      "+propertyType);
           System.out.println(" Square Footage:     "+squareFootage);
           System.out.println(" Number of Bedrooms: "+noBed);
           System.out.println("");
           System.out.println("");
       for(int i = 0; i<12; i++)
           System.out.println("Rental for month " + (i+1) + " : " + array[i]);



           break;
           default:
             System.out.println("Invalid selection");
             break; 
            }
         }
       }while (option!=0);
       }
       }
```

Now I need to display the 12 different User entered numbers in a Different Case, Due to this all being part of a switch method. Is there a way to do this, I have tried the very simple code Like

```
          System.out.println("Rental for month 1: "+i(1));
```

But it says "cannot find symbol- method i(int)"

I just want to declare them, Is there any way?

Comment: It seems like you're trying to index into your loop variable, an integer, with a constant, when you should be indexing into your array (which remains the same) with your loop counter.

Comment: @CosmicComputer Can you write that in answer form with instructions on how to do so? I'm pretty useless at code at this point :3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this-->
This will print rent for each month..

```
for(int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
    System.out.println("Rental for month " + (i+1) + " : " + array[i]);
```

One more edit in your code should be made..

```
     double[] array = new double[12]; 

     for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) 
     {
         System.out.println( "Enter Rental for month[" + (i+1) + "]" );
         array[i] = keyboardScanner.nextDouble();
     }
```

Comment: It says cannot find variable array, I already have an array All i need to do is to print the already made array that the user will basically "fill out"

Comment: I dont want it to print as soon as they type it.. it is being called in a seperate menu option, A different case in a switch statement.

Comment: @JakeGrim: Ohh.. so what do you want in your switch case? Will the user explicitly enter the month for which he needs the rent for?

Comment: No they will literally enter what rent they payed 12 different months, that is already sorted, I wish to call the 12 numbers they entered and put it in a different statement. Basically giving an overview of what they typed.

Comment: @JakeGrim: ok.. I am getting confused.. Isn't the code that I wrote doing that? My code will print the rent they entered/payed for 12 different months..

Comment: Im not sure, I'm doing the edits now on my main code. Post back in a moment to check.

Comment: It still cannot find the variable Array

Comment: Entire code is Posted, Can you do anything with it?

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.println("Rental for month 1: "+i(1));
```

What is `i` here ? Looks like a method which you dont have. You have to do following in a loop

```
System.out.println("Rental for month " + (i+1) + " : " + array[i]);
```

Comment: It doesnt seem to find the variable array, The i would be the name of the array.